# Export to csv in ui-grid angular.js

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am facing a problem for the last 2 days. I am trying to export to csv using angular.js from suggest site http://plnkr.co/edit/nJTsBLHKiqherNjoYYQk?p=preview. I have tried to fire an event when user clicks on "Export all data as csv" link in ui-grid with property **exporterAllDataFn**. Event is fired when we click on "Export all data as csv" link first time, but in the second time, the click is not firing the event. I want to call that event for every click.

Please help. For your understanding I have copied the code:

```
exporterAllDataFn: function() {
    return getPage(1, $scope.gridOptions.totalItems, paginationOptions.sort)
    .then(function() {
      $scope.gridOptions.useExternalPagination = false;
      $scope.gridOptions.useExternalSorting = false;
      getPage = null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why are you facing such a problem? For me, the download event seems to be working fine. I several times managed to download a csv.

Comment: Thanks for the reply toubou,for me also csv is downloading from grid.But problem is I am calling the backend api inside the exporterAllDataFn method for getting all data.do onething just put Breakpoints on exporterAllDataFn after that you can able identify what's the exact problem and why event is firing only once.